# Open source Business Intelligence, from Excel to web-embeddable reports

Tags: graphs, reporting, business-intelligence

I'm looking for a Business Intelligence tool that can generate graphs and reports based on a given input. Users should be able to select different variables, indicators, etc. and then be presented with graphs, charts and analysis of the selected data.

Must have the following characteristics:

1. free or open source
2. embeddable in an website
3. input should come from Excel files

Basically, I'm looking for something like http://www.tableausoftware.com/ , but the open source equivalent to this one, if it exists.

While trying the question, I just came across http://art.sourceforge.net/. I.m looking into it now, but any other suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't confuse reporting, ETL and BI software. BI software, as it says, adds a layer for business intelligence, usually by letting you define intermediate objects based on underlying data (queries, aggregates). It presents the end user with entities that are separated from the actual data, and often specialists design the intermediate level. ETL tools will let you extract and transport data, and usually do some aggregation along the way. Your last link is simply reporting software that makes graphs and reports.

Comment: The boundaries between BI/ETL/reporting are not well defined (one reason: people misuse the term BI to sell their ETL/reporting tools) but your question implies that BI is *not* what you want. I suggest you rewrite your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Pentaho CE](http://community.pentaho.com/) is the perfect tool for this.

It allows you to define sources (for instance Excel, a database, etc), then draw reports and graphs, which are presented on a web interface, and can be embedded in your website.

It is free and open source.

It also does ETL, cubes, dashboards, etc if you need.

Comment: There's 30 day trial available, so it's not free.

Comment: I fixed my link, thanks! 30 day trial is the Enterprise version. The Community Edition is free forever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Talend ETL](http://www.talend.com/resource/extract-transform-load.html):

- free and open source
- founded in 2005.
- supports all major DBMSs like PostgreSQL, SQL server and so on, as well as [Microsoft Excel files](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tFileInputExcel).
- can export jobs as web pages and [can even expose an ETL Job as a Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14749634/395857) using Talend ESB.

[image]